# How to add controls to Interface Builder Gallery?

Tags: ios, user-controls, interface-builder

I am looking to ship an iOS sdk and was wondering if there is a way to add a custom button to the Gallery list in interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

i just add the similar ui component, and change the class name of this component. looking forward to better idea.